# Spring MVC Integration Test with Selenium

Tags: java, spring, selenium

I want to do an integration test on my SpringMVC application using Selenium, with something like:

```
@Test
public void mytest() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("localhost:8080/myapp/mycontroller");
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".oi"));
    assertThat(elements, hasSize(1));
}
```

Is it possible to "run" my app, the same way that my `mvn tomcat7:run` would do, and then perform my selenium tests?

#### Update:

I'm using Spring 4.0.x. I already have Unit Tests for every classes on my webapp, but I need an Integration Test. My **controllers are already being tested with MockMVC** and spring-test-framework... but I would like to do a selenium integration test.

Comment: why don't you try to use cargo maven2 plugin, here is a good example: http://www.alexecollins.com/content/tutorial-integration-testing-selenium-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot o tries, i ended up with a base class for my Selenium Integration tests:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import static io.github.seleniumquery.SeleniumQuery.$;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class SeleniumAcceptanceTest {
    private static final String WEBAPP_FOLDER = "../../src/main/webapp";
    private static final String APP_CONTEXT = "/myapp";
    private static final int ANY_RANDOM_PORT_AVAIABLE = 0;

    static Server server;
    protected static String urlBase;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void prepareTests() throws Exception {
        startWebAppServer();
        $.browser.setDefaultDriver(new FirefoxDriver());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void finalizaTests() {
        $.browser.quitDefaultBrowser();
    }

    private static void levantarServidorDeAplicacao() throws Exception {
        server = new Server(QUALQUER_PORTA_DISPONIVEL);
        String rootPath = SeleniumAcceptanceTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".").toString();
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(rootPath + WEBAPP_FOLDER , "");
        webapp.setContextPath(APP_CONTEXT );
        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.start();
        while (true) {
            if (server != null && server.isStarted()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        int port = server.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort();
        urlBase = "http://localhost:" + port + APP_CONTEXT ;
    }

}
```

And then, a test class extends this class:

```
public class AlertasAcceptanceTest extends SeleniumAcceptanceTest {

    @Test
    public void alertas_index__must_show_table_with_4_lines() {
        //given
        doLogin();
        //when
        $.browser.openUrl(urlBase + "/alertas/" );
        int linesInTheTable = $("table tr").size();
        //then
        assertThat(linesInTheTable , is(4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering a question with a question, but... 1) do you have to use Selenium or could it be a jUnit test? 2) which version of Spring MVC do you use? Spring 3.2 added a VERY neat feature that lets you spin up mock MVC and execute HTTP requests against it.  This way you don't have to worry about starting/stopping your server and all your tests are done from "within" the app itself.  Here is a snippet:

```
@Test
public void addAsUser() throws Exception {
    TodoDTO added = TodoTestUtil.createDTO(null, "description", "title");
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/todo")
            .contentType(IntegrationTestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(IntegrationTestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(added))
            .with(userDetailsService("user"))
    )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(IntegrationTestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(content().string("{\"id\":3,\"description\":\"description\",\"title\":\"title\"}"));
}
```

Full article can be found [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-migrating-to-spring-3-2/).

Comment: Hello! I'm using Spring 4.0.x. I already have Unit Tests for every classes on my webapp, but i need an Integration Test. My controllers are beeing tested with this method you said, but i would like to do a selenium test. =].

Comment: Found a solution, posted as answer. Thanks